# How to remove a job from mongodb in agenda jobs? in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create a Nodejs mongodb api that takes a job id from the body and then delete/cancel that job which is schedule with the help of agenda package in nodejs how can i do this thing? currently its not working its giving me a error that "No jobs found" but when i check my db there are jobs so how to delete that job? when i schedule the job it automaticity creates a agendaJobs collection in my mongodb database

```
router.delete('/canceljob', async (req, res) => {
    const { _id } = req.body;
    try {
      const jobs = await agenda.jobs({ _id });
      if (jobs.length === 0) {
        return res.json({ message: 'Job not found' });
      }
  
      await jobs[0].remove();
  
      return res.json({ message: 'Job canceled and deleted successfully' });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).json('Server error');
    }
});
```

Comment: are you sure you are sending an existing _id?

Comment: @GreenChicken yes i am sure that i am sending an existing _id 
_id
6462086cc48b4b7122a0bc3b
name
"deleteUser"

data
Object
priority
0
shouldSaveResult
false
type
"normal"
nextRunAt
2023-05-29T10:24:44.581+00:00
lastModifiedBy
null